# Telerik RadGrid disappears for a second when changing page

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I have Telerik RadGrid, which I fill with some data from a stored procedure.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadGrid2.DataSource = Utils_PA.GetData_From_SQl("SPname");
    RadGrid2.DataBind();
}
```

I have RadAjaxLoadingPanel and RadAjaxManager on page.

This is my markup:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
        <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadGrid2">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid2" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" UpdatePanelCssClass="" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>

<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server"></telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
        <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid2" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="30"
            AllowFilteringByColumn="True" GroupPanelPosition="Top" CellSpacing="-1" GridLines="Both">
            <GroupingSettings CollapseAllTooltip="Collapse all groups"></GroupingSettings>
            <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevNumericAndAdvanced" Position="TopAndBottom" PageSizeControlType="RadComboBox"></PagerStyle>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
```

It all works fine for me. BUT, when i change page on grid, or use filtering or sorting, the grid disappears for a second and then shown with sorted/filtered/new page data.

So, it works correct, but How to solve this problem with disappearing? I try use RadAjaxLoadingPanel, like in Telerik Demos for show Loader. It works, but it doesn't fix grid's disappear.

Comment: **Typo** alert: it's **disappear** (one "s", two "p") - not "dissapear"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using advanced data binding method and call the Rebind() method whenever you would like to refresh the grid: [Advanced Data-binding (Using NeedDataSource Event)](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-binding/understanding-data-binding/server-side-binding/advanced-data-binding-(using-needdatasource-event))

```html
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid2" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid2_NeedDataSource">
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

```cs
protected void RadGrid2_NeedDataSource(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    RadGrid2.DataSource = Utils_PA.GetData_From_SQl("SPname");
}
```

Note: Avoid calling the Databind() method when using advanced databinding. 
Also, Rebind() method should never be called inside the NeedDataSource event, as it will enter into an endless loop and will crash the server.